# TextInput not updating when wrapped in Flexible wrapped in Row

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate

When I change a variable `person.postalCode` in setState the TextInput is not updated when wrapped in Flexible in Row. If its not wrapped then it works fine.

**This does work:**

```
JDTextfield(
        text: person.postalCode,
        onChanged: (value) {
          person.postalCode = value;
        },
 ),)
```

**This does not work:**

```
Row(children: [
    Flexible(child: JDTextfield(
        text: person.postalCode,
        onChanged: (value) {
           person.postalCode = value;
        },
     ),)
],),
```

This is how i update the variable:

```
setState(() {
      if(prefs.getString("person_plz") != null) person.postalCode = prefs.getString("person_plz");
    });
```

Where JDTextField is my own widget which basically returns a TextFormField.

Comment: `JDTextfield` is StatefulWidget ?

Comment: Yes it is. I just found a solution, after giving JDTextfield a unique key depending on the text it works. Still do not understand why this is necessary in this case and in 99% of the times it is not: key: Key(person.postalCode)